# Guava / Spark Issue

Tags: apache-spark, guava, emr

My Spark verions is 2.2.0 it works locally but on EMR with same versions it gives below exception.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted. at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:215) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:438) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:474) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:488) at DataFrameFromTo.dataFrameToFile(DataFrameFromTo.scala:80) at Migration.migrate(Migration.scala:196) at DataMigrationFramework$$anonfun$main$6.apply(DataMigrationFramework.scala:257) at DataMigrationFramework$$anonfun$main$6.apply(DataMigrationFramework.scala:255) at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160) at DataMigrationFramework$.main(DataMigrationFramework.scala:255) at DataMigrationFramework.main(DataMigrationFramework.scala) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635) Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 4.0 failed 16 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.15 in stage 4.0 (TID 115, ip-10-124-29-109.ec2.internal, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire(I)D at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcDI$sp(DynamoDBRelation.scala:138) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:137) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:137) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:137) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:131) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:131) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:115) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261) ... 8 more Driver stacktrace: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1690) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1678) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1677) at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1677) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:855) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1905) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1860) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1849) at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:671) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:188) ... 46 more Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire(I)D at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcDI$sp(DynamoDBRelation.scala:138) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:137) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:137) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:137) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:131) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:131) at com.github.traviscrawford.spark.dynamodb.DynamoDBRelation$$anonfun$scan$1.apply(DynamoDBRelation.scala:115) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:438) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261) ... 8 more
Errors!

Comment: But who is going to read all that?

Comment: clearly the issue is `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.acquire(I)D`. So instead of posting that long error message, shorten it to include only the main error and post your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this error is to use the shade plugin for maven. Add this to your pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This will create an upper jar with the same name including only a shaded guava inside.